# Comparing items in a String Array with items in an ArrayList of Hashmaps

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashmap

So I have two String arrays:

```
String[] a = {"Tony", "33", "male", "New York"};
String[] b = {"John", "33", "male", "Chicago"};
```

Then I have an ArrayList of HashMaps:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list =
[{"name": "John", "age": "33", "gender": "male", "city": "Chicago"}],
[{"name": "Tony", "Age": "33", "gender": "male", "city": "New York"}];
```

So I get array a or b first from another method. I want to then compare that the 'name' or the value at index 0 in the string a or b is the same as 'name' value in the ArrayList, String a or b value at index 1 which is '33' is the same as 'age' value in the ArrayList and so forth.
I have tried the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
    assertEquals(b[0], list.get(i).get("name"));
    assertEquals(b[1], list.get(i).get("age"));
    assertEquals(b[3], list.get(i).get("city"));
}
```

But the problem is, it works for only one of the string lists, i.e. it would only work if I get string b first because at i = 0, the ArrayList has same values as that of string b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] a = {"Tony", "33", "male", "New York"};

List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = ...;

boolean found = false;
for(final Map<String, String> map : listOfmaps) {
    if(a[0].equals(map.get("name"))
            && a[1].equals(map.get("age"))
            && a[2].equals(map.get("gender"))
            && a[3].equals(map.get("city"))) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!found) {
    // raise the alarm - nothing matched
}
```